# How to restart WPF animation/storyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have an hotkey that flashes a prompt text over the UI and then disappears. But the issue is, my storyboard flashes only once in its lifetime which also means it fires the Completed event once.

When I press the hotkey, the grid that holds the TextBlock becomes visible, but the animation no longer plays and the completed no longer fires.

I need those to work so that each time the grid becomes visible, the animation restarts from the start and then fires the completed event which will set the visibility of the grid to false.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding InfoTextVisible, ElementName=MyMainWindow}">

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Completed="InfoTextAnimation_Completed" FillBehavior="Stop">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" Completed="DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames_Completed">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:00.00" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:01.00" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:01.50" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoText, ElementName=MyMainWindow}" Name="timoti" Foreground="White" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

New code:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding InfoTextVisible, ElementName=MyMainWindow}">

    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SpinStoryboard">

                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:00.00" Value="0"/>
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:01.00" Value="1"/>
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:01.50" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:02.00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                        </BeginStoryboard>
                            
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SpinStoryboard"></StopStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoText, ElementName=MyMainWindow}" Name="timoti" Foreground="White" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Question title is misleading. The problem is not a restart of the Storyboard, but instead that the Loaded event is apparently called only once.

Comment: Oh I see, not sure what event I should be using instead.

Comment: Why eventtrigger instead of normal trigger for the property visiblity? So if I understood you correct instead of `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">` use `<Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">`

Comment: @RandRandom: thx i just tried that it seems to work but then I lose the ability to have a Completed event. So I added another animation to turn off visibility in the end, to hidden but it doesn't stop. It repeats forever. Not sure what I am missing? I just want the bound visibility to be false after the animation finishes.

Comment: @RandRandom: added the new code.

Comment: @JoanVenge - sorry, I am bad with animations, only pointed out an obvious mistake, can't see an obvious mistake any more, so I am out of ideas

Comment: @RandRandom: thx a lot, it seems closer to right approach i think.